# Non-sudo alternatives to get the current time zone?

Tags: terminal, command-line, time, timezone

`sudo systemsetup -gettimezone` will return the current system set time zone to the command line but it requires `sudo`.

`date "+%z"` will return the offset (e.g. +0900) and `date "+%Z"` will return the time zone short code (e.g. JST).

Is there another way, either command, executable or API? My searches have turned up nothing. I'm writing a CLI terminal program (not Objective-C/Swift) within which it would be helpful to have access to whatever the system currently is set to.

Any help or insight will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/etc/localtime` is a symlink pointing to the currently used timezone. So you can use

```
$ readlink /etc/localtime
/var/db/timezone/zoneinfo/Europe/Istanbul
$ readlink /etc/localtime | sed 's#/var/db/timezone/zoneinfo/##g'
Europe/Istanbul
```

Note:
`sudo systemsetup -gettimezone` prints `Time Zone: Europe/Istanbul` for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's an API.  The method `date(1)` uses. You can read the [source](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/date.c) (freely available), you note the method it uses, you use it in your own program.

Reading the [source](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/date.c) for `date(1)` leads to it using the library function `fprintftime()` in function `show_date()` which leads to the generic `strftime()`.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html